# How can I get the EC2 instance ID from a Cloudwatch Alarm (or EventBridge Rule)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I am currently trying to build a solution that will automatically expand an EBS volume when it gets below 10% free space. Here is my idea /plan to do so,

1. CW Alarm
2. EventBridge Rule monitoring for alarm state change
3. EB Rule invokes Lambda Function (function will start a Step Functions state machine to complete the process)
4. State Machine will run various lambda functions/SSM Docs to expand EBS, extend in the OS and do some error checking.
5. SNS Notifications to finish

However, my main issue is trying to get the necessary data needed for the volume expansion. The CW Alarm does not have the instance ID in the alarm data. So I cant create the Event Bridge pattern based on the instance ID.

My main 2 questions are,

1. Is my proposed idea even possible?
2. How can I get my CW Alarm to send the instance ID of the EC2 instance that triggered the alarm?

Comment: How is the CloudWatch alarm defined? What metric is it using? You haven't included any details about your first item `1. CW Alarm`.

Comment: I have the agent installed on EC2 and is monitoring free disk space. The alarm is triggered when free space is less than 10%. I have this alarm set to trigger a Lambda function. However, the function (and subsequent items) needs the instance ID of the machine that triggered the alarm. Currently cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: Instance ID should be one of the dimensions in the CloudWatch metric the alarm is configured to use. That info is passed inside the Event object wen the Lambda function is triggered, as shown in this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html

Comment: Mark, thank you for the clarification! Due to various reasons, I was looking at incorrect information (and alarm data). Also, I had my Lambda function configured wrong so I was under the impression it wasnt getting the ID when in fact it was the entire time. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It's next to impossible since free space is a file system metric and such metrics are not exposed to CloudWatch (at least not without some agent running on EC2).

A more straightforward approach would be:

1. Assign an IAM role to your EC2 instance with enough permissions to modify its own volume(s)
2. Have a script run on your EC2 instance (i.e. a cron job) and monitor free space.
3. When free space drops below your threshold, the script will modify the instance volume using AWS SDK (i.e [aws CLI: modify-volume¶](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-volume.html)). Then perform any OS specific tasks (i.e. grow filesystem with [resize2fs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html))

I also suggest configuring an upper limit for volume size to avoid high costs in case of misconfigurations/script bugs. Volumes can only grow; shrinking involves a lot of manual work and data transfer.